# Sorting object in JavaScript by value

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have an object like this one

```
{0:"first",2:"second",5:"first"};
```

I want to create a new object like this one:

```
{'first':{0:{value1:0,value2:0},5:{value1:0,value2:0}},'second':{2:{value1:0,value2:0}}}
```

How can I achieve this.

Comment: I think {'first':[0,5],'second':[2]} would be nicer :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code (i dont test it). 
thenew is the output, and theold is the input.

```
var thenew = {};
for(var k in theold) {
  var v = theold[k];
  if(!thenew[v]) {
    thenew[v] = {};
  }
  thenew[v][k] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash:

```
var transformedObject = _.transform(yourObject, 
function(r, v, k){
   if(!r[v]){r[v] = {}}; r[v][k] = {};
})
```